# Правда ли, что слово судебный произошло от слова судьба, а не суд?

Tags: этимология, словообразование

Сейчас в качестве прилагательного к слову *суд* используют *судебный*, хотя мольба - молебный, свадьба - свадебный, цельба - целебный.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У Черных есть **прямой ответ на этот вопрос.**

Судебный — исторически от ***судьба*** в значении "**суд, судилище, правосудие, приговор".** Именно в этом смысле обычно употреблялось  это слово,  которое известно в др.-рус. языке с  XI века.

Дальнейшее развитие значения: правосудие — божий суд (приговор небесных сил) — рок/предопределение.

Уже в 1073 году при переводе книги Флавия "История иудейской войны" использовано соответствие **божий суд — судьба**.

**В современном языке:** **суд — суд/ебн/ый.**  Сравнить: врач — врач/ебн/ый, хвалить — хвал/ебн/ый, лечить — леч/ебн/ый, съедать — съед/обн/ый.

Суффикс ***ОБН/ЕБН*** используется для образования прилагательных, мотивированных существительным или глаголом.

Answer (score 4):

Исторически слово *судебный* связано с сущ. *сѫдьба* в значении 'суд'. В древнерусских текстах можно найти подходящие контексты, например:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения].

От слова  *сѫдъ* образовалось прилаг. *сѫдьныи*, но в современном языке оно — *судный* — устарело.

Но в современном словообразовании *судебный* должно рассматриваться как производное от сущ. *суд*, потому что объяснить значение слова *судебный* можно наиболее кратко именно с помощью слова *суд* — 'связанный с судом' (т. н. критерий Винокура).

Answer (score 1):

Да, прилагательное *судный* устарело и употребляется только в устойчивых выражениях или в церковной речи. И это правда, что **судебный** исторически произошло от слова **судьба**, которое в те незапамятные времена одним из значений (наиболее распространённым) имело как раз **суд, судилище**. Прилагательное **судебный** и было образовано от этого значения.

Информация взята из статей **суд** и **судьба** этимологического словаря Черных.