# Огонь, огнь, гнев

Tags: этимология

Можно ли отнести слова "огонь", "гнев" и "гнести" к этимологически однокоренным, учитывая наличие в старославянском производной от слова "огнь" формы огневи, по аналогии с коневи, мечеви и господеви.

Возможно как-то связано:

ст.-слав. врачь -> врачеви -> врачевный

Примечание:

враче**б**ный этимологически от врачь**б**а (см. [судебный -> судьба](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/448066/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%BB%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B4%D1%8C%D0%B1%D0%B0-%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B4))

Answer (score 1):

Почему бы и нет? Страсти разжигаются, эмоции накаляются... Огонь — реакция окисления, возникающая в определённых условиях (в среде, где присутствует кислород, то есть, в определённом пространстве), при которой выделяется тепловая энергия. Гнев — тоже реакция, возникающая в определённой среде (эмоциональной), при которой выделяется энергия, только не тепловая, а психическая.
В словаре Преображенского А. Г. (к коему я испытываю большее уважение, нежели к другим этимологам) есть забытое русское слово "гнетити" - разжигать огонь, которое показывает трансформацию лексемы  "огнь". Вот копия:
"гнетити др. гнещу, гнетиш зсиисигать, вздувать огонь из горячаго угля. севск. загнет шесток, печурка, куда сгребаются угли из печи; загнетка, друг. диал. загнеть, подгнета, гнетья, гнетуха, огнитье".
Вопрос о том, что "гнев" происходит от "гной", остаётся открытым за недоказанностью. Я провожу свой анализ и высказываю свое мнение. А семантически "гнев" гораздо ближе к "огню", чем к "гною".

Comment: Может, всё-таки не сам огонь реакция окисления, а горение?

Comment: По поводу гной и гнить: https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B3%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C. Интересно, что в германских языках ранее означало "тереть", что, в принципе, также можно отнести к огню учитывая самый древний способ его получения.